# Scala: Why does isInstanceOf[List[Any]] not work?

Tags: scala

I was trying to solve Problem 7 of the [99 Scala Problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) and I encountered some difficulty in figuring out the type of a `List` that can contain any type. So I looked at the answer and saw that it was `List[Any]`. I proceeded to code out an implementation as follows:

```
def flatten(lst: List[Any]): List[Any] = lst match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x::xs =>
        (if (x.isInstanceOf[List[Any]]) { flatten(x) } else { List(x) }) :::
        flatten(xs)
}
```

However, this gives me the following compile error:

```
[error] <filename omitted>:<line number omitted>: type mismatch;
[error] found   : Any
[error] required: List[Any]
[error]                (if (x.isInstanceOf[Any]) { flatten(x) } else {List(x) })
[error]                                                    ^
[error] one error found
```

Changing `isInstanceOf[List[Any]]` to `isInstanceOf[List[_]]` gives the same compilation error.

After a short google search and consulting [this solution](https://github.com/rumblesan/99-Scala-Problems/blob/master/src/main/scala/P07.scala), I implemented this:

```
def flatten(lst: List[Any]): List[Any] = lst match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x::xs => x match {
        case x: List[_] => flatten(x) ::: flatten(xs)
        case _ => x :: flatten(xs)
    }
}
```

which works perfectly fine. So why does the Scala compiler think that `x` has type `Any` when, in order to get inside that block, it has to pass `x.isInstanceOf[Any]`, which makes it of type `List[Any]` ? Is this a compiler bug, or is this some part of Scala which I don't understand?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `x` is the head of a `List[Any]`: it's an `Any`, hence the error message you're getting. You need to cast it to a `List[Any]`, which pattern matching lets you do quite elegantly:

```
def flatten(lst: List[Any]): List[Any] = lst match {
  case Nil               => Nil
  case (x:List[Any])::xs => flatten(x) ::: flatten(xs)
  case x::xs             => List(x) ::: flatten(xs)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas! That is a great oversight on my part.

Answer (score 2):

Just because a value passes the `.isInstanceOf` check doesn't change it's type. It's still an `Any`. But it can be cast to `List[Any]`

So, I think you need to do

```
(if (x.isInstanceOf[List[Any]]) { flatten(x.asInstanceOf[List[Any]]) } else { List(x) }) ::: flatten(xs)
```

I'm not sure, but I think that the reason the

```
case x: List[_] => flatten(x) ::: flatten(xs)
```

version works is that it both does the check and the cast.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
case x::xs =>
```

`x` is bound to the head of the list. So if the list has type `List[Any]`, the head of course has type `Any` (and not `List[Any]`)